# Sending amqp message to ibm mq

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

Trying to transfer messages form RabbitMQ `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter` to MQSeries `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter`. This works fine.

Actually some producers on MQSeries use IBM JMS classes like that :

```
MQMessage messageMQ = new MQMessage();
messageMQ.format = "        ";
messageMQ.persistence = 1;
messageMQ.correlationId = MQ_MESSAGE_CORRELATION_ID;
messageMQ.write(message.getMessageData());
MQPutMessageOptions putMessageOption = new MQPutMessageOptions();
putMessageOption.options = 8194;
MQQueue queue = openQueue(destinataire, 8208);
queue.put(messageMQ, putMessageOption);
```

I tried using transformer between amqp and jms like this :

```
<int:transformer id="testTransformer" ref="testTransformerBean" input-channel="fromRabbit"
         method="transform" output-channel="toJms"/>


public MQMessage transform(Message<?> msg) throws Exception {

    MQMessage result = new MQMessage();
    result.format = "        ";
    result.persistence = 1;
    result.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;

    String test = "message to send ";
    result.write(test.getBytes());
    return result;
}
```

What is the type of Object storing in msg.getPayload()? How can i convert it into a String object?

Implementing this method, i have an exception because the outbound need a JMS message and not a com.ibm.mq.MQMessage!

```
Cannot convert object of type [com.ibm.mq.MQMessage] to JMS message
```

Is this way correct?

Or should i remove the outbound-channel and use a service activator instead with specific code for IBM?

Thanks for your help

Regards

**Edit following Artem's answer**

Following the jms outbound configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="queueManager" value="${queueManager}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${hostName}" />
    <property name="port" value="${port}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${channelName}" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="jmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${queueManager}" />
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="${queueName}" />
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory_cred"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/> 
</bean> 

<bean id="connectionFactoryCaching"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory_cred" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${BRIDGE_MQ_OUTBOUND_SESSION_CACHE}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice" id="requestHandler">
    <property name="trapException" value="false"/>
    <property name="onFailureExpressionString" value="#this"/>
    <property name="failureChannel" ref="processChannel1"/>
</bean>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter   channel="channelRmqMQ" 
                                    id="jmsOut" destination="jmsQueue" connection-factory="connectionFactoryCaching" delivery-persistent="true" 
                                    explicit-qos-enabled="true" session-transacted="true" >
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="requestHandler" />
    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>                                         
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: That is not MQ JMS code. It's using the MQ Java classes - a more direct representation of the underlying MQI.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your `transform` method? Are you trying to create a JMS Message? If so then shouldn't it be returning something that resembles `javax.jms.message` which should be created using a create method on a `javax.jms.JMSContext` object?

Comment: I try ton convert the message to a MQMessage. I need to use this class because some property are set on the message used by consumers (like defined in my question). How can in convert the payload (coming from amqp Rabbitmq) into a String? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If your AMQP message comes with the `text/*` `contentType`, then its body is converted to string automatically by the out-of-the-box `SimpleMessageConverter` in the `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter`:

```
     if (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("text")) {
            String encoding = properties.getContentEncoding();
            if (encoding == null) {
                encoding = this.defaultCharset;
            }

            try {
                content = new String(message.getBody(), encoding);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var8) {
                throw new MessageConversionException("failed to convert text-based Message content", var8);
            }
```

Otherwise you need to place a simple transformer in between to convert a `byte[]` to string:

```
<object-to-string-transformer>
```

The `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` is exactly for JMS protocol interaction, so, your `MQMessage` is not going to be accepted there. That's why you get that `Cannot convert object of type [com.ibm.mq.MQMessage] to JMS message` exception.

Yes, you can use IBM MP API directly in some custom `service-activator`, however I would suggest to take a look into *JMS to MQ* bridge on IBM WebSphere. Then you need only to configure an appropriate connection factory and use it from the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiMqConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${mqConnectionFactory}"/>

<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jndiMqConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="username" value="${mqLogin}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${mqPassword}"/>
    </bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="myMqQueue" jndi-name="queue/myMqQueue"/>

<bean id="mqQueueJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="myMqQueue"/>
</bean>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="myMqChannel" jms-template="mqQueueJmsTemplate"/>
```

Comment: Getting a message as a String is ok!

I allready use a `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` and it works very fine ;-) (see my edit in the question)

Previous JMS code was sending other properties not defined in jms standard , like 

 `messageMQ.format = "        ";`

So i would like to do the same treatement in my outbound channel. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try to map all those custom properties into the `headers` using `header-enricher` before sending to the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`. The  `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` will map those custom headers into the `jmsMessage.setObjectProperty()` and I hope they are going to be remapped to the `MQMessage` on the WebSphere already by the JMS bridge.

Comment: I tried to use a header enricher and try to update the message format like `<int:header name="format" expression="'MQSTR   '" overwrite="true"/>`. The `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` is called and setting the property `jmsMessage.setObjectProperty(propertyName, value);` but unfortunately in my MQExplorer the format is not updated.Thanks for your help